# Foreign Key Problem in SQL

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I just wanna ask coz I created a table with a column with two primary keys as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE Parent(
Mother varchar(50) NOT NULL,
Father varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(Mother, Father),
Organization varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
```

Then I am trying to create another table which will have a foreign key to the table shown above:

```
CREATE TABLE Child(
Name varchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Child_Mother varchar(50) REFERENCES Parent(Mother),
Child_Father varchar(50) REFERENCES Parent(Father),
Sibling varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
```

So I basically am trying to references two columns on the Child Table to a single column from the Parent table with two primary keys. Is this even possible? Thank you very much! :)

*Sample Tables only. But the actual are similar to this.

Comment: It might be a dupe, but that's okay.  Please select the answer that helped you the most/that is correct.  Deleting this question outright would penalize all the people who tried to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
CREATE TABLE Child(
    Name varchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Child_Mother varchar(50),
    Child_Father varchar(50),
    Sibling varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Foreign Key (Child_Mother, Child_Father) references Parent(Mother, Father)
);
```

Since you are creating a primary key which consists of two columns, you need to refer to them together.

What paxdiablo said is true. You are creating a composite primary key which consists of two columns. I would suggest you to use a [Surrogate Primary Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key).

**Edit**

```
CREATE TABLE Child(
    id bigint NOT NULL auto_increment,  // an "id" column
    Name varchar(50) NOT NULL unique,
    age int not null,
    primary key (id)    // "id" column is being declared as surrogate primary key
);
```

**Second Edit**

```
create table Subject(

    id int not null,
    Subject_ID varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Subject_Description varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    Subject_SID int references Student(Student_ID),
    Unit varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE Subject ADD CONSTRAINT subject_unique UNIQUE (Subject_id, Subject_Description);

create table Schedule(
    Day_MTWTHF varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    TIME_HH varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    subject_id int not null,                   -- my newly added column
    Schedule_SID int references Student(Student_ID),
    foreign key(subject_id) references Subject(id)
);
```

Comment: what if I need 1 of the two columns and reference it to a single column of another table? would that be possible? :)

Comment: @Kim Rivera: You should not do that, because that is against the primary key/foreign key relation concept. If you need to maintain a reference in the database, use foreign keys. If you still want to relate two columns of two different tables, you can achieve it using triggers/procedures. But still it is a bad idea since you are duplicating data into two different tables, and you have to update each one of them for every insert/update. This property is always a bad thing in database.

Comment: What I mean is this example There is a table wherein I have to use the Mother column as a foreign key? Meaning I won't be using the father column in this table. Is that possible? :) Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But you have to declare "Mother" column in "Parent" table as unique. Then you can add a reference to this column from any other table.

Comment: But what if I still need the Father table for some other purpose? See what I really wanted to achieve here is like this: Table 1 has two columns namely Father and Mother both are Primary Keys; Table 2 has 2 columns wherein one of the two columns is a Foreign Key to the Father from Table 1; Table 3 has 2 columns wherein one of the two columns is a Foreign Key to the Mother from Table 1. Hope this makes sense. Thank you very much for helping me. :)

Comment: @Kim: I will suggest you to use a surrogate key. Define an "id" column in table 1, then refer to it from the other tables.

Comment: i'm not sure I know how to use a surrogate key :D how do I do it? can you show me some pointers pleasE? :)

Comment: @Kim: Which database are you using ?

Comment: okay so it's like this. this is the actual table definitions that i'm trying to do. 


create table Subject(
Subject_ID varchar(50) NOT NULL,
Subject_Description varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(Subject_ID, Subject_Description),
Subject_SID int references Student(Student_ID),
Unit varchar(50) NOT NULL
)

create table Schedule(
Day_MTWTHF varchar(50) NOT NULL,
TIME_HH varchar(50) NOT NULL,
Schedule_SID int references Student(Student_ID),
Schedule_Subject_ID varchar(50) references Subject(Subject_ID)
)

Comment: i'll attach this on my original post. please see my edit too :) thank yoU!

Answer (score 4):

You haven't created a "table with a column with two primary keys", you've created one with a single composite primary key.

And what you are doing is indeed possible but not in the way you are doing it.

The problem is that you can have two `Parent` rows with the same `Mother` and different `Father`. But your foreign key relationship on `Child_Mother` will need a *single* instance of `Mother` in the `Parent` table otherwise it won't know which row it's referring to.

You can either have a combined column in the child which references the conbined primary key as you have it, or you can separate the `Parent` rows.

By that, I mean a parent table wouldn't normally put two people in a single row, it would normally have one row per person and the child would simply reference two separate rows in the `Parent` table, one for the mother and one for the father.

---

In terms of your *actual* tables:

```
create table Subject(
    Subject_ID varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Subject_Description varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Subject_ID, Subject_Description),
    Subject_SID int references Student(Student_ID),
    Unit varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
```

This is not actually normalised since the subject description almost invariable depends on the subject ID. I think the primary key should probably just be on subject ID. By all means have another *index* on subject description but it shouldn't be part of the primary key.

I'm still not sure that you understand what I'm saying so I'll try to clarify. The line:

```
PRIMARY KEY(Subject_ID, Subject_Description)
```

does *not* make two primary keys, it makes a *single* primary key made up of the two columns (id and description). Because of that, it is possible to have two rows with the same ID provided that the description is different.

So a foreign key reference to the ID column is *not* possible. Let's say you had two rows:

```
ID  Subject  Other
--  -------  ---------
 7  Maths    blah blah
 7  Physics  yada yada
```

and then tried to add to the schedule table a row with `Schedule_SID` set to 7. That will choke because the DBMS wouldn't know *which* 7 you're referring to. So it shouldn't even let you set up that foreign key constraint because the target column isn't unique.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say your choice of primary key is poor for the Parent table. It looks like you're using names. What happens if you've got two seperate couples whose names match up? John & Jane Smith with Alice and Bob for children, under your design, would also be the same John & Jane Smith from the next town over who've got Charlie and Dolores for kids, even though in reality they're completely unrelated.

Names are invariably a bad choice for keys, as names can be repeated. Using something guaranteed to be unique, such as an auto-incrementing integer, would be far safer, and would allow you to keep the J&J Smith from Springfield seperate from the J&J Smith from Shelbyville.